# How to search in multiple json data in python?

Tags: python, json

Suppose I have a lot of JSON entries, all of which contain two fields, `a` and `b`. When reading each JSON (let’s say we read the values `a_0` and `b_0` for `a` and `b` respectively), I’d like to see how many JSON entries have `b = a_0`. Is there an efficient way to do that? Should I turn it to a database if the data is > 10GB? The code will be in Python

Edit0: The total data size will be >100GB so it's necessary to scale the code. And that might probably mean I cannot fit the data into the memory.

Edit1: Basically we are not seeing whether data['a'] == data['b']. I'd like to see: for a specific json entry with a_0 and b_0, how many counts in the rest of the json entries that meets the requirement a_0 = b. Hope this time it's clearer.

Comment: Yes, for data of that magnitude you should use a database.

Comment: What have you tried? would it be a one time thing? does it need to run multiple times? 10gb is not a lot of data, but it may not fit in your memory. You could still parse that in a few seconds, but it may not be enough if your application demands a faster response.

Comment: Updated the question. The data might not be able to fit into the memory size.

Answer (score 0):

For large sets of data you should definitely use a database. If you let us know what kind of application you are developing we could maybe recommend a certain database engine for you.

However, for smaller sets of data, the Python code would be:

```
list = filter(lambda json: json['a']==json['b'], json_data)
```

An even more efficient way of doing is to use list comprehensions:

```
list = [json for json in json_data if json['a']==json['b']]
```

Obviously, if you are using a database, you would just query.

Comment: If I cannot fit the data into the memory is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Which memory exactly?

Comment: I'm having a machine with 16GB memory and the data is 5 times larger than this. That is to say, I cannot load all entries into the memory to do fast in-memory search.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you've got a file containing multiple JSONs.

The most memory-efficient method is as follows:

```
import json


def valid_json_count(filename):
    counter = 0
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            data = json.loads(line)
            if data['a'] == data['b']:
                counter += 1
    return counter
```

It processes the file line by line and doesn't hold all the data in memory

But in general turning your data into a database would be the best solution. Any DB can easily handle such a simple problem. In case you want a quick and dirty solution, take a look at [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) - it comes with Python and works out of box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is that, I need to find the position a and b in different json entry. That is to say, suppose I have a specific json entry with a_0 and b_0. I'd like to iterate all of the other entries to see: how many counts that data["b"] == data_specific["a"]